# How i can Make Status Bar in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

i want to set status bar at the bottom of screen and it should display one button left side and one right side. you can see my Screen at below. 
my code is like this..

```
private void BottomLayout() 
    {
        Bitmap topBg = Bitmap.getBitmapResource(ImageName.topbar);
        final Bitmap topBg1 = cmn_fun.resizeBitmap(topBg, SCREEN_WIDTH, topBg.getHeight());
        HorizontalFieldManager hfmbottom = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH)
        {
            protected void paintBackground(Graphics graphics) 
            {
                graphics.drawBitmap(0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH,topBg1.getHeight(), topBg1,0,0 );             
                super.paint(graphics);
            }
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.sublayout(topBg1.getWidth(), topBg1.getHeight());
                setExtent(topBg1.getWidth(), topBg1.getHeight());
            }

        };

        Bitmap imgprv=Bitmap.getBitmapResource(ImageName.btn_prev);
        Bitmap imgprv_sel=Bitmap.getBitmapResource(ImageName.btn_prev_sel);     
        btn_prev=new CustomButtonField(0, "", imgprv_sel, imgprv, Field.FIELD_LEFT);
        hfmbottom.add(btn_prev);

        Bitmap imgnext=Bitmap.getBitmapResource(ImageName.btn_next);
        Bitmap imgnext_sel=Bitmap.getBitmapResource(ImageName.btn_next_sel);        
        btn_next=new CustomButtonField(0, "", imgnext_sel, imgnext, Field.FIELD_RIGHT);
        hfmbottom.add(btn_next);


        setStatus(hfmbottom);

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: here add this btn.setPadding(0, 0, 0, Display.getWidth()-btn_prev.getWidth()-btn_next.getWidth());

Answer (score 3):

I am posting you only the status bar panel.

Actually in the HorizontalFieldManager it does create problem.

Therefore found out the following way and it is working. It does add extra code but it works

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.DrawStyle;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.GridFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;

class SampleBottomPanelScreen extends MainScreen {

private HorizontalFieldManager title_bar;

private VerticalFieldManager btn1_manager;
private ButtonField btn1;
private VerticalFieldManager btn2_manager;
private ButtonField btn2;
Bitmap bg_image;

public SampleBottomPanelScreen() {

    //bg_image = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("backgroundImage.png");

    btn1_manager = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.FIELD_LEFT) {

         protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
         {
                int displayWidth = Display.getWidth() / 2;
                int displayHeight = Display.getHeight();

                super.sublayout( displayWidth, displayHeight);
                setExtent( displayWidth, displayHeight);
         }  
    };

    btn2_manager = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.FIELD_RIGHT | VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {

         protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
         {
                int displayWidth = Display.getWidth() / 2;
                int displayHeight = Display.getHeight();

                super.sublayout( displayWidth, displayHeight);
                setExtent( displayWidth, displayHeight);
         }  
    };

    title_bar = new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH){

        public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(0x2bb1ff);
            graphics.clear();

            super.paint(graphics);
        }

        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
        {
            int displayWidth = Display.getWidth();
            int displayHeight = Display.getHeight() / 8;

            super.sublayout( displayWidth, displayHeight);
            setExtent( displayWidth, displayHeight);
        }   
    };

    btn1 = new ButtonField("Submit", ButtonField.LEFT | ButtonField.FIELD_LEFT);
    btn2 = new ButtonField("Cancel", ButtonField.RIGHT| ButtonField.FIELD_RIGHT);

    btn1_manager.add(btn1);
    btn2_manager.add(btn2);

    title_bar.add(btn1_manager);
    title_bar.add(btn2_manager);

    this.add(title_bar);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

try layout manager class

```
    package com.doapps.blackberry.layouts;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;

public class LayoutManager extends Manager 
{
    int n;
    public LayoutManager(int n) 
    {
        super(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);
        this.n =n;
    }

    protected void sublayout(int width, int height)
    {
        if(n==2)
        {
            Field first = getField(0);
            Field second = getField(1);
            layoutChild(first, this.getPreferredWidth(), this.getPreferredHeight());
            layoutChild(second, this.getPreferredWidth(), this.getPreferredHeight());
            setPositionChild(first,0, getPreferredHeight() -first.getHeight());
            setPositionChild(second,getPreferredWidth()-second.getWidth(), getPreferredHeight() -first.getHeight());

            setExtent(width, height);
        }
        if(n==1)
        {
            Field second= getField(0);
            layoutChild(second, this.getPreferredWidth(), this.getPreferredHeight());
            setPositionChild(second,getPreferredWidth()-second.getWidth(), getPreferredHeight() -second.getHeight());
            setExtent(width, height);
        }
    }
    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return 45;
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return Display.getWidth();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use GridFieldManager. Rearrange the following code fragment to your needs and play with paddings ...

```
    private HorizontalFieldManager createRightTab () {

        HorizontalFieldManager hMgr = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_RIGHT);
        ImageButtonField button = new ImageButtonField ( Bitmap.getBitmapResource(res.button_1), button_w, button_h);
        button.setFocusListener(this);
        hMgr.add(button);

        return hMgr;
    }

    private HorizontalFieldManager createLeftTab () {

        HorizontalFieldManager hMgr = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_LEFT);
        ImageButtonField button = new ImageButtonField ( Bitmap.getBitmapResource(res.button_2), button_w, button_h);
        button.setFocusListener(this);
        hMgr.add(button);

        return hMgr;
    }

    public void GridControlScreen() {

        int w = net.rim.device.api.system.Display.getWidth();

        gridMgr = new GridFieldManager(1, 3, 0);
        gridMgr.setColumnProperty(0, GridFieldManager.FIXED_SIZE, (button_w));
        gridMgr.setColumnProperty(1, GridFieldManager.FIXED_SIZE, (w-(2*button_w)));
        gridMgr.setColumnProperty(2, GridFieldManager.FIXED_SIZE, (button_w));

        HorizontalFieldManager hMgr_a = createLeftTab();
        HorizontalFieldManager hMgr_center = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        HorizontalFieldManager hMgr_b = createRightTab();

        gridMgr.add(hMgr_a);
        gridMgr.add(hMgr_center);
        gridMgr.add(hMgr_b);

        add(gridMgr);
    }
```

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void BottomLayout() 
    {
        Bitmap topBg = Bitmap.getBitmapResource(ImageName.topbar);
        final Bitmap topBg1 = cmn_fun.resizeBitmap(topBg, SCREEN_WIDTH, topBg.getHeight());
        HorizontalFieldManager hfmbottom = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH)
        {
            protected void paintBackground(Graphics graphics) 
            {
                graphics.drawBitmap(0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH,topBg1.getHeight(), topBg1,0,0 );             
                super.paint(graphics);
            }
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.sublayout(topBg1.getWidth(), topBg1.getHeight());
                setExtent(topBg1.getWidth(), topBg1.getHeight());
            }

        };

        Bitmap imgprv=Bitmap.getBitmapResource(ImageName.btn_prev);
        Bitmap imgprv_sel=Bitmap.getBitmapResource(ImageName.btn_prev_sel);     
        btn_prev=new CustomButtonField(0, "", imgprv_sel, imgprv, Field.FIELD_LEFT);
        hfmbottom.add(btn_prev);

        Bitmap imgnext=Bitmap.getBitmapResource(ImageName.btn_next);
        Bitmap imgnext_sel=Bitmap.getBitmapResource(ImageName.btn_next_sel);        
        btn_next=new CustomButtonField(0, "", imgnext_sel, imgnext, Field.FIELD_RIGHT);
        btn_next.setPadding(0, 0, 0, Display.getWidth()-btn_prev.getWidth()-btn_next.getWidth());
        hfmbottom.add(btn_next);


        setStatus(hfmbottom);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this another way which we can set Field Left and right side.
http://keraisureshvblackberry.blogspot.in/2012/02/there-are-very-common-there-there-are.html