# BlackBerry - statusbar overlapping screen

Tags: blackberry, overlap, horizontalfieldmanager, mainscreen

I have defined a status bar in my BlackBerry app as a HorizontalFileManager containing 2 buttons, but when the bar is displayed, it overlaps the bottom part of the screen. If I drag the screen, I can read the information on the bottom, but as soon as I release it, it disappears again under the status bar.

How can I avoid this? I've tried with setPadding(), setBorder(), setExtent(), but nothing changed.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093691/how-i-can-make-status-bar-in-blackberry/9094982#9094982

Comment: What are you using to implement your screen? The MainScreen class provides an implementation via setStatus(Field status).

Comment: I'm using MainScreen::setStatus(), and it's working. Except, when I scroll down, I can't see the bottom elements of the screen, the status bar is hiding them.

Comment: see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942225/tab-bar-in-blackberry-without-toolbarmanager/8967671#8967671 and In that code change here: super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), 150);
        setExtent(Display.getWidth(), 150); 
like.....: super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), bottomPanel.getHeight());
        setExtent(Display.getWidth(), bottomPanel.getHeight()); try this one;Then you can get like this image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/74795641@N06/6734580553/in/photostream

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, but I didn't want to reimplement the wheel.

The current solution looks like this:

```
public class VerticalSpacerField extends VerticalFieldManager {
    private final int preferredHeight;

    public VerticalSpacerField(final int preferredHeight) {
        this.preferredHeight = preferredHeight;
    }

    protected void sublayout(final int maxWidth, final int maxHeight) {
        super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
        setExtent(maxWidth, preferredHeight);
    }
}
```

and

```
add(new VerticalSpacerField(statusBar.getPreferredHeight()));
```