# Click event is working outside the button

Tags: blackberry

I am putting a button in a bottom bar of the screen. Bottom bar is basically a horizontal field manager with a background image. Now this button(Basically a Continue button) is used to move to next screen. but if i will click in the manager and outside the button, it is going to the next screen. So click event is working on total manager, Below is code:

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfmBtn = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_BOTTOM)
    {
        protected void sublayout(int nMaxWidth, int nMaxHeight) 
        {
            height = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("buttom_bar.png").getHeight();
            super.sublayout(nMaxWidth, nMaxHeight);
            setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
        }

        public int getPreferredHeight() 
        {
            return height;
        }

        public int getPreferredWidth() 
        {
            return screenWidth;
        }
    };
    hfmBtn.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("buttom_bar.png")));
    btnContinue = new CustomButtonImageField("Continue", Bitmap.getBitmapResource("button_normal.png"), Bitmap.getBitmapResource("button_hover.png"),Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
    btnContinue.setChangeListener(this);
    btnContinue.setMargin(10, 0, 0, screenWidth/3);
    hfmBtn.add(btnContinue);
    add(hfmBtn);
```

And here is the click event :

```
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
{
    if(field == btnContinue)
    {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new SendListScreen(platformContext,strItemList));
    }
}
```

please help me.. I am testing in BB Bold 9790.

Comment: There is no other fields that have focus. So the default focus will be in the button.

Comment: Once u r in button focus when u click other area u will get that button click event.  but when u focus on other field u will not get this issue.  so add one Focusable field for testing than try to click on button ..

Answer (score 7):

Just add a `nullfield` before adding the button. And make it focus-able. That will work.

Like this add `nullField` then Add `button`.

```
hfmBtn.add(new nullField(Field.FOCUSABLE)); 
hfmBtn.add(btnContinue);
add(hfmBtn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your custom button as following:

```
hfmBtn.add(new PictureBackgroundButtonField(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Field.FIELD_HCENTER|Field.FOCUSABLE, bitmap, bitmapHover) {
    protected boolean invokeAction(int action) {
        // code to be executed when button is pressed
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: i think you are telling to do like this: btnContinue = new CustomButtonImageField("Continue", Bitmap.getBitmapResource("button_normal.png"), Bitmap.getBitmapResource("button_normal.png"), Bitmap.getBitmapResource("button_hover.png"))
  {
    protected boolean invokeAction(int action) 
    {
     UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new SendListScreen(platformContext,strItemList));
           return true;
    }
  };                                                    hfmBtn.add(btnContinue);

Comment: changed 'invoked code' with more meaningful ' code to be executed when button is pressed '

Comment: Instead of custom button, if i am putting Blackberry native buttons, it is behaving on the same way..fade up :)

Comment: Don't fed up and get inspiration here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093691/how-i-can-make-status-bar-in-blackberry maybe changing all your implementation ...

Answer (score 0):

Take the **PictureBackgroundButtonField.java** from this below link:

[PictureBackgroundButtonField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942225/tab-bar-in-blackberry-without-toolbarmanager/8967671#8967671)

and then Try this sample code:

```
public class Abc extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{   
Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon.png"),bitmapHover=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("iconHover.png");
PictureBackgroundButtonField continueBtn;
public Abc() 
{       
    createGUI();
}

private void createGUI() 
{   
    HorizontalFieldManager hr=new HorizontalFieldManager()
    {
        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) 
        {
            super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),250);
            setExtent(Display.getWidth(),250);
        }
    };
    hr.add(new LabelField("Click The Below Button", Field.FOCUSABLE));
    continueBtn=new PictureBackgroundButtonField(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Field.FIELD_HCENTER|Field.FOCUSABLE, bitmap, bitmapHover);
    continueBtn.setChangeListener(this);
    continueBtn.setMargin(50, 0, 0, 0);
    hr.add(continueBtn);
    hr.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GREEN));
    add(hr);
}

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)
{
    if(field==continueBtn)
    {
        Dialog.alert("Clicked");
    }
}           
}
```